# Is firebase enough for backend for an Angular website?

Tags: angular, firebase, web, backend

I'm developing a website in Angular and when I searched for backends I came across Firebase, so I went with that.

I implemented authentication and it is working, but now that I looked more into it, seems that a lot of people use more than firebase for backend (e.g. nodejs), my question is: why?

I'm new to Firebase, I only worked with SQL databases in the past (using mainly Laravel).
My website would be kind of simple, users can sign up and login, create posts, comments etc.
Is firebase enough? Or is it not safe? What is the difference between an SQL database and Firebase?

Sorry if this sounds dumb.

Comment: https://db-engines.com/en/system/Firebase+Realtime+Database%3BMicrosoft+SQL+Server%3BSQLite

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is overkill imo... Too much stuff you won't need, too much docs to read...

If you just need a simple backend and angular frontend I'd suggest using node for both you can combine express + socket.io for the backend serving both REST api and websockets and also "static files" (your angular app)
Here's an introductive guide

https://medium.com/@danielkagan/serve-mean-stack-using-angular-cli-f39b33dbad64

Not too sure about the quality of it tbh that was my first google result..

After you do that you can deploy to any docker based cloud service,
you could do that with google app engine in the google cloud platform and it will be free until you start using a lot of resources

http://cloud.google.com/

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer. I never used Nodejs, but since firebase is also new for me, I will go with nodejs I guess. More resources to learn I think.